# In nvd3.js is there any direct option for displaying polylines for Pie/Donut Chart with labels outside the arcs

Tags: nvd3.js, pie-chart, polyline, donut-chart

Refer [Animated Donut Chart with Labels, Legend and Tooltips](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/1984c7f2b446fffeedde) created using d3.js

[image]

I don't see any option for creating a Pie/Donut Chart with polylines for marking labels outside the arcs as per the [official documentation](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#pie).

Also it will be great if we can fill the line stoke with same color as that of the point as shown [here](http://prntscr.com/dxrpk8).